# Не работает конструктор копирования

Tags: c++

Не работает конструктор копирования. Как исправить?

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

struct Postavki  //структура
{
    int num;  //номер поставки
    int weight;  //вес руды
    float output;  //ожидаемый выход металла
    Postavki *Next, *Prev;  //Указатели на адреса следующего и предыдущего элементов списка
};
typedef Postavki *PPostavki;   //тип данных "указатель на узел"

class First  //определение класса
{
    Postavki *start, *end, *current;
public:
    First();
    First(const First & ob1);
    ~First();
    void add(); //добавление
    void show(); //вывод
    void del(); //удаление
    void SumWeight(); //суммарный вес
};

First::First()
{
    start = NULL;
    end = NULL;
    current = NULL;
}

First::First(const First &ob1)  //Конструктор копирования
{
    Postavki *objeckt1 = ob1.start;
    while (objeckt1)
    {
        current = new Postavki;
        if (NULL != start)
        {
            current->Prev = end;
            end->Next = current;
        }
        else
        {
            current->Prev = NULL;
            start = end = current;
        }
        current->Next = NULL;
        current->num = objeckt1->num;  //номер
        current->weight = objeckt1->weight;  //вес
        current->output = objeckt1->output; //ожидаемый выход
    }
}

First::~First() //деструктор
{
    while (end)
    {
        current = end->Prev;
        delete end; end = current;
    }
}


void First::SumWeight() //функция поиска суммарного веса
{
    float Sum = 0;
    current = start;
    while (current){
        Sum += current->output;
        current = current->Next;
    }
    cout << Sum << endl;
}




void First::del() // функция удаления элемента
{
    int Nodel;
    cout << "Введите номер удаляемого элемента: ";
    cin >> Nodel;
    Postavki *No = start; //создаем локальную переменную для поиска удаляемого элемента по номеру
    while (NULL != No)
    {
        if (No->num == Nodel)
        {
            if (No->Next == NULL&&No->Prev == NULL) //если элемент единственный в списке
            {
                delete No;
                start = end = NULL;
                break;
            }
            else
                if (No == start) //если элемент 1-й в списке
                {
                    No = No->Next;
                    No->Prev = NULL;
                    delete start;
                    start = No;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    if (No == end) //Если элемент последний
                    {
                        No = No->Prev;
                        No->Next = NULL;
                        delete end;
                        end = No;
                        break;
                    }
            current = No->Prev;
            current->Next = No->Next;
            current = No->Next;
            current->Prev = No->Prev;
            delete No;
            break;
        }
        No = No->Next;
    }
}

void First::add() //функция добавления элемента
{
    Postavki *temp = new Postavki; // Выделяем память под новый элемент структуры
    temp->Next = NULL;
    cout << "Введите номер элемента: ";
    cin >> temp->num;
    cout << "Введите вес элемента: ";
    cin >> temp->weight;
    cout << "Введите ожидаемый выход маталла";
    cin >> temp->output;
    if (NULL != start)
    {
        temp->Prev = end;
        end->Next = temp;
        end = temp;
    }
    else{
        temp->Prev = NULL;
        start = end = temp;
    }
}


void First::show() //функция вывода
{
    current = start;
    cout << "\nНомер | Вес   |  Выход металла\n----------------\n";
    while (current){
        cout << current->num << "     | " << current->weight << "    | " << current->output << endl;
        current = current->Next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    First ob1;
    bool fl = true;
    int buf;
    while (fl)
    {
        cout << "\n\n1.Распечатать \n2.Добавить \n3.Удалить \n4.суммарный вес \n5.Сравнение  " << endl;
        cin >> buf;
        switch (buf)
        {
        case 1: {ob1.show(); break; }
        case 2: {ob1.add(); break; }
        case 3: {ob1.del(); break;  }
        case 4: {ob1.SumWeight(); break;    }
        case 5: {fl = false; break; }
        default:cout << "ошибка\n";
        }
    }
    cout<<"Я тут"<<endl;
    First ob2(ob1);
    fl = true;
    while (fl)
    {
        cout << "\n\n1.Распечатать \n2.Добавить \n3.Удалить \n4.суммарныйм вес \n5.Сравнение \n6.Выход  " << endl;
        cin >> buf;
        switch (buf)
        {
        case 1: {ob2.show(); break; }
        case 2: {ob2.add(); break; }
        case 3: {ob2.del(); break; }
        case 4: {ob2.SumWeight(); break; }
        case 5: cout << "Первый объект:"; ob1.show(); cout << "\nВторой объект:"; ob2.show(); break;
        case 6: {fl = false; break; }
        default: cout << "ошибка\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может быть, вы удалите ненужные для понимания проблемы части программы? Очень уж много кода.

Comment: @Angus123 Это раздел вопросов, а не кода ревью. Почему вы решили, что конструктор копирования не вызывается, и где он должен вызываться?

Comment: (И если это не учебное задание, пользуйтесь `std::list` вместо собственного велосипеда.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас две проблемы с конструктором копирования.

Первая - это то, что члены класса `start` и `end` не инициализированы и имеют неопределенные значения.

Вторая проблема состоит в том, что в цикле `while` переменная `objeckt1` не меняется, а потому цикл будет бесконечным.

Конструктор копирования может выглядеть следующим образом

```
First::First(const First &ob1) : start( NULL ), end( NULL )
{
    for ( Postavki *object1 = ob1.start; object1; object1 = object1->Next )
    {
        current = new Postavki;
        if (NULL != start)
        {
            current->Prev = end;
            end->Next = current;
        }
        else
        {
            current->Prev = NULL;
            start = end = current;
        }
        current->Next = NULL;
        current->num = object1->num;  //номер
        current->weight = object1->weight;  //вес
        current->output = object1->output; //ожидаемый выход
    }
}
```

Или если ваш компилятор поддерживает стандарт C++ 2011, то консмтруктор копирования можно определить также следующим образом:

```
First::First(const First &ob1) : start( NULL ), end( NULL )
{
    for ( Postavki *object1 = ob1.start; object1; object1 = object1->Next )
    {
        current = new Postavki 
        { 
            object1->num, object1->weight, object1->output, NULL, end
        };

        end = current;

        if ( start == NULL ) start = current;
    }
}
```